# Dictionary not recognizing floating point keys

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, floating-point, key

I have a dictionary called G. When I enter `G. keys ()`, an example of the output is:

```
>>> G.keys ()
[(1490775.0, 12037425.0), (1493775.0, 12042675.0), (1481055.0, 12046305.0), (1503105.0, 12047415.0), (1488585.0, 12050685.0), (1483935.0, 12051405.0),...
```

When I use the operation `key in G` the result is false.

```
>>> (1490775.0, 12037425.0) in G
False
```

Why isn't my dictionary recognizing my keys?

```
>>> type (G.keys()[0])
<type 'numpy.void'>
>>> type (G.keys()[0][0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>> type (G.keys()[0][1])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
type(G)
<type 'dict'>
```

Comment: The floating point god is eating it?

Comment: @thefourtheye I was going to say something about using floats as dict keys, but I think you summed it up nicely!

Comment: I allowed myself to edit the title and the tag to improve the chance that people with the same problem doesn't create yet another duplicate of this question. There are at least a dozen of similar question asked every day...

Comment: Can you please tell us what `type(G.keys()[0])` is, and what `type(G.keys()[0][0])` and `type(G.keys()[0][1])` are?  If those really are Python floats and Python tuples, then you shouldn't be seeing this behaviour.

Comment: (And for good measure, what's `type(G)`?)

Comment: I've tried the `type` operation and added it to the original question.

Comment: @JC11 : are you sure ? I'm very surprised to have a `numpy.int32` printed as `1490775.0` !

Comment: My mistake! I have already had my G changed from further testing. I will change the Edit, once I returned them to their original

Comment: The proper `types` are added to the question.

Comment: How was `G` constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be how you arrived in this situation:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([(1490775.0, 12037425.0)], dtype=[('foo','<f8'),('bar','<f8')])
arr.flags.writeable = False

G = dict()
G[arr[0]] = 0

print(type(G.keys()[0]))
# <type 'numpy.void'>

print(type(G.keys()[0][0]))
# <type 'numpy.float64'>

print(type(G.keys()[0][1]))
# <type 'numpy.float64'>

print(type(G))
# <type 'dict'>
```

A tuple of floats is not a key in `G`:

```
print((1490775.0, 12037425.0) in G)
# False
```

But the numpy.void instance is a key in `G`:

```
print(arr[0] in G)
# True
```

---

You will probaby be better off not using `numpy.voids` as keys. Instead, if you really need a dict, then perhaps convert the array to a list first:

```
In [173]: arr.tolist()
Out[173]: [(1490775.0, 12037425.0)]
In [174]: G = {item:0 for item in arr.tolist()}

In [175]: G
Out[175]: {(1490775.0, 12037425.0): 0}

In [176]: (1490775.0, 12037425.0) in G
Out[176]: True
```