# Convert floating point array to integer array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, integer

I have an array known as `start`. I am trying to use it as a key in a dictionary known as `G`.

Here is a sample of the array:

```
array([(1497315, 11965605), (1502535, 11967915), (1501785, 11968665),
       (1520325, 11972295), (1522905, 11972805), (1504545, 11972865),
       (1500465, 11973075), (1489695, 11975205), (1485855, 11978775),
       (1499535, 11978955), (1508205, 11981745), (1521315, 11982615),
       (1501215, 11983335), (1508595, 11985225), (1503045, 11986635),
       (1522425, 11987745), (1512705, 11988255), (1519035, 11989185)...
```

len (start) is 50

I want to convert start into an integer type so I can use it as a key in my dictionary.

I've tried `type (start) is int` to confirm that it is not an integer. Start was created from two columns of integers representing x and y coordinates.

Related to previous question:

[Dictionary not recognizing floating point keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226725/dictionary-not-recognizing-floating-point-keys)

Comment: What do you mean convert to integer? The elements of the array tuples are already integers.

Comment: How is start initialised? If it's an array I'm not sure why (or how) you'd convert it to int.

Comment: This post is related to OP's last post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226725/dictionary-not-recognizing-floating-point-keys he was using floats before

Comment: Array and list are two different thing in Python, yours look like Numpy's ndarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is with reference to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22226725/1903116)

```
array = [(1497315.0, 11965605.0),(1502535.0, 11967915.0),(1501785.0, 11968665.0)]
print map(tuple, map(lambda x: map(int, x), array))
# [(1497315, 11965605), (1502535, 11967915), (1501785, 11968665)]
```

with list comprehension

```
print [[int(item) for item in items] for items in array]
```

If you want to convert the keys of your dictionary to `int`, you use `dictionary` comprehension

```
d = {(15035.0, 119915.0): 'b', (15085.0, 119665.0): 'c', (14975.0, 11965.0): 'a'}
print {(int(k[0]), int(k[1])):v for k, v in d.iteritems()}
# {(15085, 119665): 'c', (14975, 11965): 'a', (15035, 119915): 'b'}
```

Comment: This prints the conversion, is there a way to change it permanently. When you type`print array` again the values are still floats.

Comment: `array = {(int(k[0]), int(k[1])):v for k, v in d.iteritems()}` :)